# Join two collection in mongoDB and extract out data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am using MongoDB 3.6 for my project. 
I have 2 collections "users" and "follow". I want to extract out details of user's followers and following (like an Instagram app).

**users collection**

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "abc",
    "age" : "26"

},
{
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "age" : "22"

},
{
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "qwe",
    "age" : "23"

}
```

**follow collection**

```
{
    "id" : "2",
    "follow id" : "1"

},
{
    "id" : "3",
    "follow id" : "1"

},
{
    "id" : "1",
    "follow id" : "2"

},
{
    "id" : "2",
    "follow id" : "3"

},
{
    "id" : "1",
    "follow id" : "3"

}
```

Now i want following list of id 2 So id 2 is following id 1 and id 3
So, Output should be like this

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "abc",
    "age" : "26"

},
{
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "qwe",
    "age" : "23"

}
```

For that, I am using $lookup aggregation. But this is not giving the desired output which I want.
Here is my code -

```
Follow.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup:{
            from:"users",
            localField:"id",
            foreignField:"id",
            as:"fromItems"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: ["$fromItems", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
    },
    { $project : 
        { 
            fromItems : 0 
        } 
    }
], callback)
```

For more understanding please refer the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwiBI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get following list of id `2` you can use following query:

```
Follow.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "id": "2" }
    },
    { 
        $lookup:{
            from:"users",
            localField:"follow id",
            foreignField:"id",
            as:"fromItems"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: ["$fromItems", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
    },
    { $project : 
        { 
            id : "$follow id",
            name: 1,
            age: 1 
        } 
    }
])
```

So the point here is that you have a relation between `id` and `follow id` and after `$lookup` phase `follow id` becomes the new `id` since it's parent-child relation.

EDIT:
3.4 solution below

```
Follow.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "id": "2" }
    },
    { 
        $lookup:{
            from:"users",
            localField:"follow id",
            foreignField:"id",
            as:"fromItems"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: "$follow id",
            from: { $arrayElemAt: ["$fromItems", 0 ] }
        }
    },
    { $project : 
        { 
            id : 1,
            name: "$from.name",
            age: "$from.age" 
        } 
    }
])
```

Comment: Done that but the result is not that what I want. Result is - 
{
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "age" : "22",
    "follow id" : "1"
}
{

    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "age" : "22",
    "follow id" : "3"
}

Comment: @RajAmitSingh you shouldn't get `follow id` since I'm renaming it to `id `using $project ? Did you run exactly the same query ? I'm getting `{ "name" : "abc", "age" : "26", "id" : "1" }
{ "name" : "qwe", "age" : "23", "id" : "3" }`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me but now the problem is $mergeObjects is not running at 3.4 MongoDB, is there is an alternate solution to $mergeObjects.

Comment: @RajAmitSingh I've added second solution, it uses $project instead of $mergeObjects